# SQLAlchemy multiple foreign key paths linking the tables

Tags: sqlalchemy, orm

I have read most of the question related to this problem but I still cannot understand the core of it and therefore I must ask again since I cannot fix it.

```py
class Branch(Base):
   __tablename__ = "branches"
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
   name = Column(String, unique=True)
   
   head_commit_oid = Column(String, ForeignKey("commits.oid"))
   
   repository_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("repositories.id"))
   repository = relationship("Repository", back_populates="branches", foreign_keys=[repository_id])


class Repository(Base):
   __tablename__ = "repositories"
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement= True)
   name = Column(String, unique= True)
   head_oid = Column(String, nullable= True, default= None)
   
   current_branch_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("branches.id"), nullable=True)
   current_branch = relationship("Branch", foreign_keys=[current_branch_id])

   commits = relationship("Commit", back_populates="repository")
   branches = relationship("Branch", back_populates="repository")
```

When I use these models I get the error: "Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Repository.branches - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table."

I do understand that there are many similar questions, For example: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61746229/multiple-foreign-key-paths-linking-the-tables). But I am just unable to apply them to my own code.